# jquery scrollLeft auto?

Tags: jquery

What i'm trying to do is if the mouse is over the 'next' button it scrolls to the right at a slow speed and if the mouse isn't over the 'next' button it stops scrolling?

here is my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/nCCRy/14/

```
$(function() {

$('#next-button').hover(function() {
    $('#display-container').animate({
        'scrollLeft': '+=120px'
    }, '500');
});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out jQuery's [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method:

```
var $container = $('#display-container'),
    scroll = $container.width();
$('#next-button').hover(function() {
    $container.animate({
        'scrollLeft': scroll
    }, 500);
}, function(){
    $container.stop();
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nCCRy/17/

Comment: thanks but how do i make it scrollLeft till the end of the div on hover?  i put 120px but i just want it to scrollleft infinite until it reaches the end of the div.

Comment: Also, what is the terminology when you add a comma after the first function and put another function?  Alternate function?

Comment: @user892134 - Check out [the documentation on `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). It takes 2 parameter: one for `mouseenter`, one for `mouseleave`.